# how to make sprites stick together in game maker?

Tags: game-maker

I don't know how to get sprites to stick to each other so they become one big object instead of tiny little pieces, for example:

attaching a thruster to a box, then the thruster stays in that spot while pushing the box, and also is there a certain term for what I'm talking about?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! It's usually easier for the community to help you out if you post some examples of the code that you currently have, as well as what you have tried and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: I don't have any code, my brain wont think of any possible solutions on how to achieve this, ive seen some people do it like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixXl4QL1uuA

Comment: i don't want anyone to do it for me, just want some ideas on how to even combine images to make them one object

Comment: @Alpha i just figured it out! thank you! :)

Comment: I'm glad! Sorry I wasn't able to help, I literally know nothing about Game Maker. If you wish, you can answer your own question so that in the future somebody else will benefit from it. That's actually encouraged around here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also attach all parts to one of the objects, it would sort of look like:

`//Main object
    x = 5;
    y = 20;`

```
//other object step event
x = obj_main.x + <any value to put it where you want>;
y = obj_main.y + <any value to put it where you want>;

//This will force the parts to follow the main object.
```

`

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array, defined in the 'main' object to use a sort of grid to define where each piece is and then either draw each individual sprite, based on its position in the array, originating from the 'main' object's coordinates. Or just create an individual instance of an object if you would like to have additional functionality by trading off some performance.

For more information on arrays and how to position sprites and objects based on set coordinates, check out the GML documentation provided below:

Arrays:
https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/001_gml%20language%20overview/401_06_arrays.html

lengthdir:
https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/maths/real%20valued%20functions/lengthdir_x.html

Answer (score 0):

what I did was make the object disabled, so when I press left and right it doesn't go anywhere, only the other piece would move, but when it came into contact it allowed the other piece to move along with it, and set its speed to the corresponding objects speed, in simpler term, when I collide with it, it turns the movement on and goes in the same direction as the current object in the same speed, making it look like its sticking